# Preenchendo arrays utilizando uma função recursiva?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho uma função recursiva que divide um determinado número em partes, exemplo: Numero 259,  ao passar pela função ele ficará assim: 200 e 59, preciso armazenar estes números em um `array`.

**Exemplo:**

No primeiro laço do loop preciso que seja armazenado o numero 200 na primeira posição do array e assim por diante com todos outros

Código da Função:

```
function ValorFinalArray($soma) 
{
    $tam = 0;
    do 
    {
        $tam = strlen($soma);
        if ($soma > 100 && $soma < 200) 
        {
            echo "cento <br/> e <br/>";
            echo substr($soma, -2);
            break;
        }
        $valor = $tam == 2 ? $soma : substr($soma, 0, $tam - ($tam - 1)) . str_repeat("0", $tam - ($tam - ($tam - 1)));

        if ($soma == "0")
            break;

        echo "<br/>numero: " . $valor . "<br />";

        if ($tam <= 2)
            break;

        echo "<br/> e "."<br />";

        $soma = $soma - $valor;
        $tam++;
    }
    while ($tam > 1);
}

echo ValorFinalArray(259);
```

o retorno deve ficar assim: `array([0]=>200, [1]=> 59)`

Preciso que me deem uma ajuda de como posso fazer este processo.

Comment: Essa função não parece recursiva. Onde está a recursão?

Comment: Não faria mais sentido o retorno ser `array([0]=>200, [1]=> 50, [2] => 9)` ? O que seria mais simples até. Ou qual a lógica por detrás do algoritmo?

Comment: então, este algoritimo eu uso ele para fazer a verbalização dos numeros numa central telefonica, no caso o valor das contas em atraso do cliente.
eu recebo de um web service o valor, faço o tratamento e passo para esta função, com o retorno dela eu consigo fazer com que a central "diga" para o cliente o valor em reais da conta dele.

Comment: Concordo com vc que seria mais lógico o retorno ser desta forma `array([0]=>200, [1]=> 50, [2] => 9)`, mas eu havia tentado com outros numeros e não tinha dado certo.

Comment: `$f = new NumberFormatter("pt", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(259);` Assumindo que tem pelo menos a versão `5.3.0` do php e a extensão `php_intl` ativada no `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

É só pegar os valores gerados e inserir em um `array` no caso foi criado uma variável `$ret` do tipo `array` e os valores gerados, adicionados nesse `array` e no final dessa função, dá um `return $ret`, ***exemplo***:

```
function ValorFinalArray($soma) 
{
    $ret = array();
    $tam = 0;
    do 
    {
        $tam = strlen($soma);
        if ($soma > 100 && $soma < 200) 
        {
            echo "cento <br/> e <br/>";
            echo substr($soma, -2);
            break;
        }
        $valor = $tam == 2 ? 
           $soma : 
           substr($soma, 0, $tam - ($tam - 1)) . 
           str_repeat("0", $tam - ($tam - ($tam - 1)));

        if ($soma == "0")
            break;

        $ret[] = (int)$valor;

        if ($tam <= 2)
            break;

        $soma = $soma - $valor;
        $tam++;
    }
    while ($tam > 1);
    return $ret;
}

var_dump ( ValorFinalArray(259) );
```

Acredito que o seu código só sirva pra esse número em especifico, mas, não levei em conta o que essa função iria gerar, mas, demonstrei como pode ser feito esse retorno em um `array`.

[Exemplo Online](https://repl.it/KAZt/4)

Comment: obrigado Virgilio, era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando.